# HTML email - text formatting in banner varies across multiple platforms

Tags: html, email, text, formatting

I've been tasked to update our company's banner by end of this week. I am not an email designer so I've had to make due with using a current template, swapping out the banner, and doing Google research. It looks GREAT in Outlook and the web version and was quite proud of myself. However, I decided to try to test it to my Gmail and also check my Outlook through my phone and it looks terrible!! How deflating!

In Outlook, the font size is perfect, and it's perfectly centered. On my phone and on my desktop on Gmail, the text is MUCH smaller and stays at the top left. The code is pasted below (removed our company banner and replaced with Shutterstock for posting here). Is there a way to carry this format across all platforms?

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="headerCopy" style="max-height: 132px; min-height: 132px;" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td background="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/holographic-iridescent-surface-wrinkled-foil-260nw-1090516967.jpg" bgcolor="#0033a0" name="Cont_0" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%; max-width: 100%" valign="top"><!--[if mso]>
                                  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:132px;">
                                    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/holographic-iridescent-surface-wrinkled-foil-260nw-1090516967.jpg" color="#0033a0" />
                                    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                                               <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="600"><tr><td width="40">&nbsp;</td><td align="left" valign="top" width="540"><![endif]-->
                                    <div>
                                    <p align="left" style="font-size: 40px; color: #0033A0; margin-left: 82px; margin-top: 46px; 0"><strong>Test Text Placement</strong></p>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--[if mso]><td width="20">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
                </v:textbox>
                </v:rect>
                <![endif]--></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

[Gmail version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wHZU.jpg)